# TortoiseSVN - How can I update/fix/delete a plugin revision I messed up at /tags/x.y.z?

Tags: plugins, svn

Using Win7 and TortoiseSVN, I created a plugin, followed the directions for first committing trunk, then created a branch/tag at /tags/x.y.z.

Except I forgot to update the version number at /my-plugin/trunk/my-plugin.php before I committed trunk and tagged the new revision.

The revision shows up in the plugin tags and as an alternative version -- but not the current stable version on wordpress.org/plugins/my-plugin/. Wordpress.org doesn't recognize it as the current stable version, even though I wrote it as such in readme.txt, perhaps because it still has the old version number at /my-plugin/trunk/my-plugin.php and /my-plugin/tags/x.y.z/my-plugin.php.

I want to either 
a. delete the bad revision at /my-plugin/tags/x.y.z so I can recreate it correctly, or
b. edit/update the bad revision at /my-plugin/tags/x.y.z.

I tried switching to /my-plugin/tags/x.y.z so I could merge trunk to x.y.z, but I got this message:

```
Switch E:\subversion\wordpress plugins public\my-plugin to http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin/tags/x.y.z, Revision HEAD
'http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/my-plugin/tags/x.y.z' shares no common ancestry with 'E:\subversion\wordpress plugins public\my-plugin'
```

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: For "shares no common ancestry" error - show `svn log -v` for repo root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way:

- checkout tag
- fix version number
- commit